# How can I reset NX sessions?

Tags: java, remote, session, nx, x2go

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and x2goserver.  The x2go sessions boot into openbox, which starts a java program as defined in its autostart profile.

Question is, if I make an update to this java program, how do I force all the open x2go sessions to close down such that the java program is closed, session is terminated and they would have to reconnect and promptly experienced an updated java program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view all sessions with `x2golistsessions_root` and kill sessions with `x2goterminate-session <session id>`. I don't believe you can force them to re-connect automatically. To kill all the sessions, you could run this as root:

```
x2golistsessions_root | awk -F'|' '{ print $2 }' | xargs -I % x2goterminate-session %
```